# gulp browser-sync not serving json files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, browser-sync

I have an issue where i am not able to serve `json` files from my sub-folders. Below is the code:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Static server
gulp.task('connect', function() {
    browserSync.init({
      server: {
        baseDir: "app/"
      }
    });
});
```

All my `static` and `angularjs` files reside inside app folder. When i navigate to `http://localhost:3000`, the page loads but the corresponding json file inside `app/data/myfile.json` does not load.

I get the below error in my console:

> POST http://localhost:3000/data/json/myfile.json 404 (Not Found)

The strange thing is when i try to load the path in my browser, the json file loads.

Comment: same issue.. have you find any solution?

Comment: there are a plus subdir `json` presents on message error that are missing on file position that you have written, is a mistake of answer or is this the error?

Answer (score 0):

At first I used this way https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-serveStatic FAIL.
But

```
const ASSET_EXTENSION_REGEX = new RegExp(`\\b(?!\\?)\\.(${config.assetExtensions.join('|')})\\b(?!\\.)`, 'i');
     const DEFAULT_FILE = 'index.html';
...
        server: {
          baseDir: './build',
          middleware: function(req, res, next) {
            let fileHref = url.parse(req.url).href;

            if ( !ASSET_EXTENSION_REGEX.test(fileHref) ) {
              req.url = '/' + DEFAULT_FILE;
            }

            return next();
          }
        }
     ...
```

> config = {assetExtensions: [
>       'js',
>       'css',
>       'png',
>       'jpe?g',
>       'gif',
>       'svg',
>       'eot',
>       'otf',
>       'ttc',
>       'ttf',
>       'json',
>       'woff2?'   ]}

SUCCESS